# remove everything between two characters with sed

Tags: sed

I'd like to remove any characters between  including them also

```
<img src=\"/wp-content/uploads/9e580e68ed249dec8fc0e668da78d170.jpg\" / hspace=\"5\" vspace=\"0\" align=\"left\">
```

I was trying

```
sed -i -e 's/<img src.*align=\\"left\\">//g' file
```

Comment: Use a proper XML/HTML parser instead of line-oriented tools.

Answer (score 0):

You do not say what version of **sed** you are using, or what shell.

With GNU **sed** and **bash**, your attempt was almost there. Try:

```
  sed -i 's/<img src[^>]*align=\\"left\\">//g' file
```

Explanation:

- `s/<img src[^>]*align=\\"left\\">/` search for `<img src_STUFF_align=\"left\">`, where `_STUFF_` cannot contain any `>`
- `//` and replace it with nothing
- `/g` and continue
- `-i` and modify the file

I believe this should work with most version of **sed** (except for the `-i`).

Comment: Yes its GNU sed and bash. Thank you Joseph it works!

Comment: @vnr: If this answer is helpful, perhaps you could accept it?

Comment: Can you please explain why `_STUFF_ ` cannot contain any `>` ? Where is no `>` in my case between `<img src` and `align=\"left\">`

Comment: The reason for using `[^>]*` instead of simply `.*` is this. With `.*`, if there were ***two*** `<img src...align=\"left\">` on one line, with text between them, then _both_ would be deleted, and the text between them would _also_ be deleted. With `[^>]*`, the text will be kept.

Comment: Furthermore, `.*` would also delete `<img src...align=\"right\"> ...blah... <...align=\"left\">`.